# how to fix ora-01652

Tags: oracle, temp, segment

I need to run a create table query, every time it takes more than one hour and a half and then it will show the error message like ora_01652: unable to extend temp segment by 8192 in tablespace xyz, how can I fix it?

Comment: also check your ctas statement to be sure the joins are correct (do you really expect to create a huge table?  If so, you should be working with your dbas in advance).  Also, I assume you aren't trying to put this in the USERS or default tablespace

Answer (score 3):

First, you may want to `alter session set resumable_timeout = 86400`.  This will pause the query instead of letting it simply fail, giving you time to look at the situation while it's happening.  As @davek mentioned, you may need to add space somewhere.  And you need to figure out why it is using so much space.

Temporary tablespace is used mostly for sorting and hashing data.  For example, if you are sorting or hash-joining a 50GB table, you will need about 50GB of temporary tablespace.  As @tbone suggested, a really bad query or execution plan could have a cross join that tries to create a massive result set that won't fit on any disk.  Make sure your joins are correct and the execution plan looks sane.  Some things to look for are `MERGE JOIN (CARTESIAN)`, or perhaps if there are some filters that are applied after hashing or sorting instead of before.  Re-gathering statistics is usually a good first step if the plan is bad.

If the query and plan are OK and you just don't have enough space, you'll need to break the query up somehow.  This could be multiple inserts instead of a single CTAS.  Breaking up queries is usually a bad idea, but is necessary in some rare cases where resources are scarce.  Or you may want to look at using [partition-wise joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_warehouse.htm) to reduce the the amount of space required.

Answer (score 1):

Either your disk is full (or almost full) or you do not have permission to extend the relevant tablespace.